# how to put array in attribute to be readable by javascript using jinja2 and google app engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, google-app-engine

I am trying to put an array from a server to a web page via jinja2 in google app engine, but I can't seem to get it so it is readable by my jQuery code.  I'm pretty new--first time I've tried something like this.

My python code looks like this (with some code removed for brevity):

```
import json
jinja2_ENVIRONMENT.filters['json'] = json.dumps

filterList = ["context","home"]
template_values = {
"filterList" : filterList
}
```

which I pass to the output by using :

```
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

the attribute in my html template looks like this:

```
filterlist="{{ filterList|json }}"
```

My problem is that the array is not readable by the javascript on the browser.  In the element inspector it looks like this:

```
filterlist="["context", "home"]"
```

while for JSON, I THINK I want something like '["context","home"]' for it to be readable by my jQuery code. [edit: it is readable, but as a string, not as an array... I'd rather not have to write a parser if I don't have to].

```
var filterList = $("body").attr("filterlist");
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything suggested above, but still had some problems. In the end, I was able to find a solution using the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.  By adding the following line to my jQuery code:

```
var filterList = JSON.parse('{"filterList":'+$tasklist.attr("filterlist")+'}');
```

I was able to access the array as filterList.filterList.

I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I suspect somehow I am not using the jinja2 python library correctly.  Nonetheless, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You're already passing JSON to the template. So just output it using:

```
filterlist={{ filterList|safe }};
```

Comment: Thank you! When I do that, the HTML attribute appears as: <body filterlist="['context'," 'home'];> which is still not readable as an array by my jQuery code... it reads it as a string.

Comment: How about `filterlist={{ filterList|json|safe }};`?